# Making Endnote library with lists of titles for multiple articles

Tags: r, excel, pubmed

I have a list of hundreds of paper titles in an Excel file.
I want to create an EndNote library with these articles. However, manually searching for each paper title to create the library is driving me crazy.
Is there a way to automatically generate PubMed searching queries with this information and import them in the EndNote library?

I could not make pubmed searching query automatically with my excel data.
I prefer R rathet than Pythorn. I don't have knowledge of Pythorn.